# Socket error "unable to connect to"

Tags: php, apache, sockets, unix, nagios

I have a server on VirtualBox with Nagios, and I would like to communicate with a socket UNIX, but a have a probleme since one week...

The apache error_log contains :

```
[Tue Jan 14 09:34:43 2014] [error] [client 192.168.2.36] PHP Warning:  fsockopen() [<a href='function.fsockopen'>function.fsockopen</a>]: unable to connect to unix:///var/log/nagios/rw/live:0 (No such file or directory) in /usr/share/nagios/jNag/server/returndata.php on line 80, referer: http://192.168.2.97/nagios/jNag/client-web/index.html
[Tue Jan 14 09:34:43 2014] [error] [client 192.168.2.36] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: errstr in /usr/share/nagios/jNag/server/returndata.php on line 82, referer: http://192.168.2.97/nagios/jNag/client-web/index.html
[Tue Jan 14 09:34:43 2014] [error] [client 192.168.2.36] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: errno in /usr/share/nagios/jNag/server/returndata.php on line 82, referer: http://192.168.2.97/nagios/jNag/client-web/index.html
```

But, in fact, the socket works, and exist...

If you have an idea... Thanks in advance

Nicolas

Comment: check permissions of the socket

Comment: plese show output of `ls -l /var/log/nagios/rw/live*`

Comment: [root@localhost /]# ls -l /var/log/nagios/rw/live*
    srwxrwxrwx 1 nagios apache 0 janv. 14 09:34 /var/log/nagios/rw/live


Thanks

Comment: I also test with this command :
`[root@localhost check_mk]# echo 'GET services' | /usr/bin/unixcat /var/log/nagios/rw/live
accept_passive_checks;acknowledged;acknowledgement_type;action_url;action_url_expanded;active_checks_enabled;check_command;check_command_expanded;check_freshness;check_interval;check_options;check_period;check_type;checks_enabled;comments;comments_with_extra_info;comments_with_info;contact_groups;contacts`
So the socket works ... I test the permissions, and i don't know where is the solution @taro @umläute